# Turning a boolean function into a method? (python)

Tags: python, methods, boolean

I'm struggling with an assignment for my programming class. The question it gives is:

1. Write a Boolean function between that takes two MyTime objects, t1 and t2, as arguments, and returns True if the invoking object falls between the two times. Assume t1 <= t2, and make the test closed at the lower bound and open at the upper bound, i.e. return True if t1 <= obj < t2.
2. Turn the above function into a method in the MyTime class.

My code looks like this:

```
class MyTime:
  
  def __init__ (self, hrs=0, mins=0, secs=0):
    t_secs = hrs*3600 + mins*60 + secs
    self.hrs = t_secs // 3600 # Split in h, m, s
    left_over_secs = t_secs % 3600
    self.mins = left_over_secs // 60
    self.secs = left_over_secs % 60

    #print (t_secs)

  def increment(t, secs):
    t.seconds += secs
    while t.seconds >= 60:
        t.seconds -= 60
        t.minutes += 1

    while t.minutes >= 60:
        t.minutes -= 60
        t.hours += 1

  def __str__(self):
    return "{0}:{1}:{2}".format(self.hrs,self.mins,self.secs)
  
  def __lt__(self,t2):
    if self.hrs<t2.hrs:
      return True
    if t2.hrs<self.hrs:
      return False
    if self.hrs==t2.hrs:
      if self.mins<t2.mins:
        return True
      if t2.mins<self.mins:
        return False
    if self.mins==t2.mins:
      if self.secs<t2.secs:
        return True
      if t2.secs<self.secs:
        return False

  def __eq__(self,t2):
    return bool(self.hrs == t2.hrs and self.mins == t2.mins and self.secs == t2.secs)
  
  def __le__(self,t2):
    return bool(self.hrs <= t2.hrs and self.mins <= t2.mins and self.secs <= t2.secs)

  def __ge__(self,t2):
    return bool(self.hrs >= t2.hrs and self.mins >= t2.mins and self.secs >= t2.secs)

  def __ne__(self,t2):
    return bool(self.hrs != t2.hrs or self.mins != t2.mins or self.secs != t2.secs)

  def __add__(self,t2):
    h=self.hrs+t2.hrs
    m=self.mins+t2.mins
    s=self.secs+t2.secs
    
    while s > 59:
      s-=60
      m+=1
    while m>59:
      m-=60
      h+=1

    sum_t=MyTime(h,m,s)
    return sum_t

  def between(self, t1, t2, t3):
    if t1.hours < t2.hours and t2.hours < t3.hours:
      return True
    else:
      return False
```

and my main/running code looks like this:

```
from MyTime import MyTime

t1 = MyTime(1,3,30)
t2 = MyTime(1,4,16)
t3 = MyTime(3,4,26)

def between(self, t1, t2, t3):
    if t1.hours < t2.hours and t2.hours < t3.hours:
      return True
    else:
      return False


print(between(t1, t2, t3))
print(t2.between(t1, t3))
```

I keep getting a "TypeError: between() missing 1 required positional argument: 't3'" error but I'm confused as to how to fix it?

I originally had it submitted with the between statement commented out in the MyTime file and that worked somehow. I might've changed something else too, but I've been messing with it too long to remember. Please help I only have one chance to resubmit it and I'm stumped!

Comment: Your `__le__`, `__ge__`, etc. implementations are wrong. Your  `__lt__` had the right idea: you check the most significant units (hours) for a difference first, and only if they're equal do you continue on to break ties with the next smallest unit (minutes), and so on. By comparison, your `__le__` is saying something like "T1 is smaller than T2 only if its hours, minutes ***and*** seconds are ***all*** smaller". But that isn't the case. E.g. 10:59 is less than 11:00, even if its 59 minutes is greater than the 00 minutes.

Comment: Expanding on my prev comment: you only really need to implement `__lt__` and `__eq__`, and all the rest can be implemented _in terms of_ those two base methods. For example, `__le__(self, other)` can be implemented as `self.__lt__(other) or self.__eq__(other)`.

Comment: That's a weird assignment. *"the invoking object"*? What? How is the function supposed to find it? Inspect the call stack or other hackery?

Answer (score 2):

Your current issie is that `def between` is a "free" function not associated as a method on the `MyTime` class. Your free function `def between` shouldn't have a `self`.

What happens is that when you call `between(t1, t2, t3)`, the arguments are assigned in a way you didn't expect, as if you did:

```py
print(between(self = t1, t1 = t2, t2 = t3, t3 = ... missing!))
```

What you want instead is to move and indent the entire `between` method to be in the `class MyTime` body, along side your other methods like you showed in your first big code block.

The issue then is that your method is taking in too many parameters. When you call it like `t2.between(t1, t3)`, the arguments don't line up with the paramters as you expected:

1. The first parameter `self` is filled in with the receiver of the method call, `t2`.
2. The second parameter `t1` is filled in with the first positional parameter of your method call, `t1`
3. The third parameter `t2` is filled in with the second positional parameter of your method call, `t3`
4. The fourth parameter `t3` is left unpopulated, because there is no third position argument in your method call.

As you see, `t3` is excess and unused. What you want is something like:

```py
class MyTime:
    # ...

    def between(self, start, end):
        if t1.hours < self.hours and self.hours < t2.hours:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

However, you should consider renaming `t1` and `t2` for clarity. Perhaps `start` and `end` would be more clear:

```py
class MyTime:
    # ...
    
    def between(self, start, end):
        if start.hours < self.hours and self.hours < end.hours:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

From there, you might reconsider the way `between` only looks at the `hours` of the various times involved. You'll probably want `start < self and self < end` instead, so that it calls your custom `<`operator (`__le__` method) to do the comparison (taking into account the minutes and seconds, not just the hours).

Comment: "*`def between` shouldn't have a `self`*": In that case, it should be decorated with `@staticmethod`.

Comment: @InSync I'm not so sure, this looks to be a free function outside the `MyTime`. Which now that I think about it... is the issue.

Comment: @InSync Just updated my answer. Can you please delete your comment so as to not pull OP off track? I think they intended this to be an instance method all along.

Comment: t1 and t2 are perfectly fine standard names for times, see for example [this](https://www.science-campus.com/physics/mechanics/kinematics/chapter2/kinematics_2_6_velocity.php). And the OP didn't make them up, they're specified in the given assignment. Better don't deviate from that. (Final code should probably just be `return t1 <= self < t2`, literally what the assignment said except for the variable name (I'd say Python standard trumps the assignment)).